# how to parse non-string values in Opencsv HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy

Tags: javabeans, opencsv

I'm using a HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy to map a csv file with a header into a JavaBean. String values parse fine but any "true" or "false" value in csv doesn't map to JavaBean and I get the following exception from the PropertyDescriptor:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

The code where it occurs is in CsvToBean, line 64:

```
protected T processLine(MappingStrategy<T> mapper, String[] line) throws  
 IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException, IntrospectionException {
    T bean = mapper.createBean();
    for(int col = 0; col < line.length; col++) {
        String value = line[col];
        PropertyDescriptor prop = mapper.findDescriptor(col);
        if (null != prop) {
            Object obj = convertValue(value, prop);
            // this is where exception is thrown for a "true" value in csv
            prop.getWriteMethod().invoke(bean, new Object[] {obj});
        }
    }
    return bean;
}

 protected PropertyEditor getPropertyEditor(PropertyDescriptor desc) throws   
       InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> cls = desc.getPropertyEditorClass();
    if (null != cls) return (PropertyEditor) cls.newInstance();
    return getPropertyEditorValue(desc.getPropertyType());
}
```

I can confirm (via debugger) that the setter method id correctly retrieved at this point.

The problem occurs in desc.getPropertyEditorClass() since it returns null. I assumed primitive types and its wrappers are supported. Are they not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by extending CsvToBean and adding my own PropertyEditors. Turns out opencsv just supports primitive types and no wrappers.

Comment: by any chance if you remember how did you actually create your own property editors?

Comment: Registering your own editor may not work because the BooleanEditor is already register. To register an editor you must call: PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(Integer.class, IntegerEmptyEditor.class);

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this same issue.  The cleanest way is probably to override getPropertyEditor like pritam did above and return a custom PropertyEditor for your particular object.  The quick and dirty way would be to override convertValue in anonymous class form, like this:

```
CsvToBean<MyClass> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<MyClass>(){

    @Override
    protected Object convertValue(String value, PropertyDescriptor prop) throws InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException {

        if (prop.getName().equals("myWhatever")) {
            // return an custom object based on the incoming value
            return new MyWhatever((String)value);
        }

        return super.convertValue(value, prop);
    }
};
```

This is working fine for me with OpenCSV 2.3.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Pritam's answer is great and this is a sample for dealing with datetime format.
`PropertyEditorManager.registerEditor(java.util.Date.class, DateEditor.class);`
You should write your own editor class like this:
`public class DateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{
    public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text){
        setValue(sdf.parse(text));}
}`